# How to predict the class before the sequence ends : Sequence classification (using RNN's/LSTM's in Keras)?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have been working with sequence classification using LSTM in Keras.
I have 200 sequences belongs to two classes either 0 or 1
Each sequence has a time step start from T1, T2, T3.....T50

How to predict the class earlier at Time step T40 (Before the sequence ends) after training?

**E.g : Training**

Given: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 --> Predict: “good”

Given: 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 --> Predict: “bad”

[image]

**Prediction : (What i needed)**

Given [1,2,3] --> Predict : 'good'

I am sure that there will be some approach/paper/sources for my above requirement.

**My Working model**

My data contains Vehicle CAN signal, dynamics data.

```
X.shape = (195,100,4) 
# 195 segments, each segment is of shape 100*4 
# every row in 100*4 corresponds to each Time step 
# each time step in 100*4 represented as t1, t2, t3,.....t100

Y.shape(195,)
# each segment out of 195 segments belongs to either 0 or 1 (2 classes)
```

Keras code

```
input_ = Input(shape=(100,4))

x = LSTM(10, return_sequences= True, activation='tanh')(input_)

x = GlobalMaxPool1D()(x) 

output = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=output)

model.compile(
  loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3),
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Training
r = model.fit(
  X,
  Y,
  batch_size=5,
  epochs=100,
  validation_split=0.1
)
```

Comment: better do not, the sentence content may vary a lot because of end words

Comment: I cannot get your point..@user8426627
For your information, i am not working with NLP or sentences, Embeddding layer. I am working with Vehicle dynamics data over time

Comment: please post a basic model for a workable example.

Comment: ok if you want it just train with varying length. You want to have 1,2,3,4,5->good, 1 2 3-> good, the second one is just another data in dataset what is pretty easy to create: 1-> good, 1,2, -> good, etc... I for dynamics data over time maybe 1D CNN  or RCNN (1D CNN -> RNN) is better choise

Comment: @NathanMcCoy kindly see my edited question above
This is what I have done till now..I am not sure whether what i did is correct..
Kindly correct me, if I am wrong

Comment: @user8426627 thanks for your suggestion..Could you please find my code what i have tried till now ..and make some suggestions in that..
Also, I cannot understand, how to implement CNN in my model. Could you please explain in detail..

Answer (score 0):

Do any tutorial how to do 1D convolution in your API. I have not worked with Keras, but it would be like:

1) Have dataset of size (batch, sequence, items), where items is of size 1 ,s oyou have like :  [[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]] ...  [[1],[2],[0]] [[1],[0],[0]]  ...] etc in a batch. If convo if of size 1, pad it with zeroes. 
Convo layer of size 3 for example is applied for each sequence :
[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]  -> convo1d -> (1,2,3)(2,3,4)(3,4,5) , where (1,2,3) is the result of map apply

2) Then the output of convo of size (batch, sequence-map_size+1, items), goes to some reccurent layer, in your case it would be many to many, means output is created and backpropagated after input of each item in sequence.

If you would send data to me i implement it in Pytorch, is realy easy

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to implement your way of approach...
Also, could you please confirm the below link solves the problem which I am looking for : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/training-an-rnn-with-examples-of-different-lengths-in-keras